# Как сделать что бы макос загружалась?

Tags: macos

Я установил макос на виртуальную машину, и установил на неё Clover из .pkg файла, который добавил папку EFI и файл boot. Так же я добавил файл CLOVERX64.efi в сам диск, но после записи VHD образа на диск мой ПК не загружался. В Windows диск отображается так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но пока я делал дамп VHD образа на диск, когда процесс близился к концу, он выдавал ошибку:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите пожалуйста, что сделать что бы макос загружалась? Процессор конечно же интел